# Django Adding Values to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, view, models

I'm trying to set up a way for users to "watch" certain items (i.e. add items to a list containing other items by other users):

```
class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Thing(models.Model):
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(WatchList, null=True, blank=True)
```

How do I add a `Thing` to a users `WatchList`?

```
>>> from myapp.models import Thing
>>> z = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=1)
>>> a = z.watchlist.add(user="SomeUser")

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

How can I add the item to the watchlist? And/or is this the appropriate way to set up my model fields? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I think you are getting confused with manytomany. You would just do `=`

Comment: Why not relate directly to the user? Or did you want to create multiple watchlists per user?

Comment: If ultimately Im trying to query to get all the `Things` that are being watched by a particular `User`, should I set up my models differently? Would it be better to place a ForeignKey from `WatchList` to `Thing`, rather than the way I described above? The ultimate goal is to query to find all things being watched by a particular user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z.watchlist` is the reference itself, it is not a relationship manager. Just assign:

```
z.watchlist = WatchList.objects.get(user__name='SomeUser')
```

Note that this assumes there is only one `WatchList` per user.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input but I am still pretty confused. Maybe I have set up my models wrong. If I want to be able to query to get all `Things` that a `User` is `Watching,` should I use a ManyToMany relationship instead? I also want to be able to get all `Users` that are `Watching` a certain `Thing`.. Sorry for the confusion on my part, but I appreciate your ideas!

Comment: Your user object has a `.watchlist_set` manager; `user.watchlist_set.get().thing_set.all()` would be all things a user is watching.

Comment: Ok well now Im super confused now. Trying `z.watchlist = WatchList.objects.filter(user__username='SomeDude')` has resulted in a `ValueError: Cannot assign "[<WatchList: WatchList object>, <WatchList: WatchList object>, <WatchList: WatchList object>, <WatchList: WatchList object>]": "Thing.watchlist" must be a "WatchList" instance.`

Comment: @NickB: That is a **list** of `WatchList` objects, your user has multiple. Get just *one* instead; `WatchList.objects.filter(user__username='SomeDude')[0]` would be the first matching watchlist.

Comment: Ok well I think I may have a problem with the way I setup my models, in that case. What I am hoping to achieve is to query for: `Thing.objects.filter(watchlist__user__username='SomeDude')` so that I can get all things that a user is watching. Have I set up my models incorrectly in that case? Sorry for the confusion on my part..

Comment: Oh wait actually I just realized that that query worked! Sometimes I guess stumbling through a problem leads to the answer! Thanks for your assistance, apologies for my oversight!

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 3):

As karthikr said you may be getting confused with manytomanyfield, if you really want an intermediary model, you might have something like this:

```
# Models:
class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='watchlists')

class Thing(models.Model):
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(WatchList, null=True, blank=True)

# Usage:
user = User.objects.get(name='???') # or obtain the user however you like
wl = WatchList.objects.create(user=user)
thing = Thing.objects.get(id=1) # or whatever
thing.watchlist = wl
thing.save()

# get users watch lists:
user.watchlists
...
```

Otherwise you might want to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-modela).

Comment: Hmm okay that makes a little more sense. How would I then query to find all items that a user is watching?

Comment: explanation added to my answer.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but I receive an `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'watchlist'`. Any ideas why?

Comment: the related name was 'watchlists' not 'watchlist'

Comment: I put that exact code into my python interpreter. With the models defined above, this code: `>>> user.watchlists` results in `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'watchlists'`. The same thing for `user.watchlist`. What am I missing? Thanks for any ideas!